# Is there a Twitter mobile application made with JQuery mobile or JQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

is there any kind of open source application that is sort of like a "clone"/"fork" of the official Twitter Mobile Application or at least close to its functionalities?

That is made using JQuery mobile or JQuery?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently did a blog post which showed how to connect to Twitter with jQuery and displays the results using a jQuery Mobile listview:

http://andymatthews.net/read/2012/03/02/Creating-a-dynamic-jQuery-Mobile-list-view-with-ColdFusion,-Mustache-templates-and-JSON-data

It might get you started in the right direction.